# Pythagorian Quadruples

Tags: python, loops, math

I got an assignment to print all of the Pythagorean quads for a number I get from the input. I wanted to ask if there is a more efficient way than what I've done (my code works)

Please note that we are only allowed to use what we have learned from the first 2 lessons so no functions and all that.

Basically what we've learned is for and while loops, input, print, and assignment. No dictionaries, no functions, nor most of the built python functions i.e `count()` (not that its relevant for this task)

The conditions for the task: `a`, `b` and `c` must be less than or equal to `n(input)` and bigger than 0.

```
a**2 + b**2 + c**2 = n**2
```

code:

```
n = abs(int(input()))
for a in range(1, n):
    for b in range(1, n):
        for c in range(1, n):
            if (n >= c) & (c >= b) & (b >= a) & (a > 0):
                if (a ** 2 + b ** 2 + c ** 2 == n ** 2):
                    print(f'{a} {b} {c} {n}')
                    continue
                else:
                    continue
            continue
```

Comment: Move the conditions as far out as possible. E.g. `(b >= a) & (a > 0)` don't need to be inside the c loop. Plus, `(a > 0)` will never be False anyway.

Comment: Why so many `continue`s? You can get rid of all of them. Just wipe them (and the empty `else`). Also, your "ands" are not doing what you are expecting. And as already said, move conditions as outside as possible.

Comment: Since permutations of a solution are obviously solutions too, it makes sense to "get rid of duplicates" by only searching for solutions such that `a <= b <= c`. In that case you can do `for b in range(a, n):` and `for c in range(b, n):`. This will make the code somewhat faster.

Comment: Also, once you have chosen `a`, `b` and `n`, then there is only one possible choice for `c`, which is the square root of `n**2 - a**2 - b**2`. If you had a function `isqrt` that returns the integer square root efficiently, you could write directly `c = isqrt(n**2 - a**2 - b**2)` rather than loop over many possible values of `c` and try them one by one.

Comment: Note that questions of the form "My code work, but could it be improved?" are better-suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com than for StackOverflow.

Comment: If you don't have a `isqrt` function to compute the square root, then at the very least you could break out of the `c` loop if you find a solution (because if you found one solution `a**2 + b**2 + c1**2 == n**2`, then you know there cannot be another solution `a**2 + b**2 + c2**2 == n**2` that differs only by `c`).

Comment: I'm sure your teacher would like it if you proposed one solution without isqrt, and another solution with isqrt. This function exists in the `math` module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isqrt ; so you can write `from math import isqrt` at the top of your program and then use `c = isqrt(n**2 - a**2 - b**2)`. Or you can write `import math` at the top of your program and then use `c = math.isqrt(n**2 - a**2 - b**2)`.

Comment: thanks everyone for the comments! i have mad adjustments and will know for the next time to post things like this 1 on StackExchange! about the issqrt: unfortunately we cant use the math module

Comment: @WalaWizon Even if you can't use the math module, if you can write text in addition to the code in your report, I strongly suggest adding one sentence to say that choosing `c` directly with an assignment would be more efficient than searching for it with a `for`-loop, if a square root function were available in python. You can write `c = √(n**2 - a**2 - b**2)` where `√` is the radical symbol for square roots. This would show the teacher that you've understood the problem and thought about it, even though in the code you only used `for`-loops as required.

Answer (score 0):

Answer with my and commentators solutions. Changes:
First: removing always right condition 
`a>0` `n>=c` 
Second: changing `var**2` to faster `var*var`
Third: changing  range of searching and changing the condition

```py
    for b in range(a - 1, n):
        for c in range(b - 1, n):
            if (c > b) & (b > a):
```

(changed  `c >=b` because now the range makes it possible)

Fourth: removing continues (because for cycle continues automatically)

The final code:

```py
        n = abs(int(input()))
        sqn = n * n
        for a in range(1, n):
            sqa = a * a
            for b in range(a - 1, n):
                sqb = sqa + b * b
                if sqb > sqn:
                    break
                for c in range(b - 1, n):
                    sq = sqb + c * c
                    if sq > sqn:
                        break
                    if sq == sqn:
                        print(a, b, c, n)
```

Execution time (on my machine)

```py
# original
# --- 7.862524747848511 seconds ---
# --- 7.8851892948150635 seconds ---
# --- 8.068974256515503 seconds ---
```

```
optimized
--- 1.9928691387176514 seconds ---
--- 1.9339394569396973 seconds ---
--- 1.8362393379211426 seconds ---
```

benchmark code:

```py
# this just for benchmarking
import time

start_time = time.time()
run = []

# n = abs(int(input()))
for nums in range(0, 3):
    for n in range(1, 80):

        for a in range(1, n):
            for b in range(a, n):
                for c in range(b, n):
                    if (c >= b) & (b >= a):
                        if a * a + b * b + c * c == n * n:
                            print(a, b, c, n)

    run.append("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
    start_time = time.time()


print(run[0])
print(run[1])
print(run[2])
```

Update 
found and fixed the bug with output: (moved last condition upper, removed `(c >= b) & (b >= a)`

```py
for a in range(1, n):
    for b in range(a - 1, n):
        for c in range(b - 1, n):
            if a * a + b * b + c * c == n * n:
                print(a, b, c, n)
```

output changed from this (for n=78)

```
4 38 68 78
4 52 58 78
18 24 72 78
20 28 70 78
26 28 68 78
28 44 58 78
38 44 52 78
```

to this (now it same with original code output)

```
4 38 68 78
4 52 58 78
18 24 72 78
20 28 70 78
26 28 68 78
26 52 52 78
28 44 58 78
38 44 52 78
```

Update 2:
code now execs in 0.8s

P.S
I'm not native english speaker, in text can be typos.

Comment: You may want to introduce break statements after each for loop. For example, when `2 * a ** 2 >= n ** 2`, there is no need to check any `b` or `c` values.

Comment: push it to the limit. ```        n = abs(int(input()))
        sqn = n * n
        for a in range(1, n):
            sqa = a * a
            for b in range(a - 1, n):
                sqb = sqa + b * b
                if sqb > sqn:
                    break
                for c in range(b - 1, n):
                    sq = sqb + c * c
                    if sq > sqn:
                        break
                    if sq == sqn:
                        print(a, b, c, n)
``` 
new version that execs in 0.8s. (original is 8s, first gen 1.9)